# What does the path in an action of the following action-mapping mean

Tags: struts

What does the path in an action of the following action-mapping mean .Does it specify the jsp page from which a request is coming (search.jsp)?

```
<action-mappings>
<action path="/search"
        type="SearchAction"
        name="searchForm"
        scope="request"
        validate="true"
        input="/search.jsp">
</action>
</action-mappings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path refers to the name of the action you call from your HTML or jsp file.

For eg -

```
<html:form action="Name" name="nameForm" type="example.NameForm">
```

The corresponding action mapping will be something like  -

```
<action path="/Name" type="example.NameAction" name="nameForm" input="/index.jsp">
<forward name="success" path="/displayname.jsp"/>
```

Check out this [link](http://www.allapplabs.com/struts/struts_example.htm) for a complete example.